# Java FTP client probably timeout issue

Tags: java, ftp-client

I've a desktop application on swing which acts as a file uploader. I simply choose a folder (by "JFileChooser") having multiple files and took the files in an array. Thereafter I created an object FTPClient after that I'm using "for loop" to extract the files. In each loop I am getting the files and through FTPClient it's uploaded to the server. If the file is successfully uploaded then I'am calling a server script which takes some time (about 2 minutes) to get respond back to my controller. If the response took so long then my loop dies to execute further. Is it timeout issue?

Thanks

Comment: Is it timeout issue - How should we know that? Provide the exception and some code.

Comment: Loops don't die. You are probably getting an exception. That exception answers your question.